# How to test that http.Redirect uses correct redirect URI?

Tags: go, testing

I have a Go backend that uses the `net/http` package. I have an endpoint that is meant to redirect using `http.Redirect` to a provided redirect URI with some generated GET parameters. I simply want to test using `net/http/httptest` and `testing` that my endpoint is redirecting to the proper URL.

I have executed the request using `ServeHTTP` and can verify that it does return the correct status code (303 in this case). I then tried accessing the Request URL to find the most recent URL that was accessed (what I assumed to be the redirect URL), but I was unable to access this variable.

```
req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://www.urlthatredirects.com"), nil)
w := httptest.NewRecorder()
MyRouterMux().ServeHTTP(w, req)
resp := w.Result()

redirectUrl := resp.Request.URL
```

In this example, I would expect the `redirectUrl` variable to contain the URL that was redirected to, but instead I receive `[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation ...]`

Any idea what could be going on? I know from manual testing that the endpoint works as intended, but I simply need to prove through the tests that it does.

Comment: Can you look at the value of the `Location` header in the response?

Comment: I'm not sure about this relating to the seg error, however if I were testing, I would be inspecting the header `Location` (and status code) in the http response and not the url per se, unless `httptest` is setup to follow redirects and you receive the followed destination. From a pure point of view, you made a request and received headers back.

Comment: [Per the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Response), `Request.Response` "is the request that was sent to obtain this Response." It has nothing to do with any redirect response received. To check for a redirect response, look at the response status code and `Location` header.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comments, I have found that I was looking for the redirect url in the wrong place. The correct way to evaluate this is to capture the url from the `Location` header.

```
w := httptest.NewRecorder()
MyRouterMux().ServeHTTP(w, req)
resp := w.Result()

redirectUrl, err := resp.Location()
```